# Cucumber HTML reports in Jenkins using python

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, cucumber

I am trying to create a test step in Jenkins using a python script. This python script will be used to automate regression tests. These tests are in a GitHub repository and what my python script will do is manipulate the requests after reading one test case at a time and send it across to the server which will return a pass or fail for that test case.

I wanted to visualize the test results of this python script and I stumbled upon Cucumber reports for Jenkins. I have installed the plugin and I wanted to know how to generate the HTML report of the tests I am going to execute using my python script.

Is there a way to create the json report in Python and feed that to the Cucumber UI plugin to generate the HTML report? Thanks! Please let me know what do I need to read/do to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, but with Java, we were doing the following:

In your Runner class, you set a path to your json cucumber report, smth like (I took this example from here: [Cucumber Report Path](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/cucumber-reports/):

```
   @CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/functionalTests",
    glue= {"stepDefinitions"},
    plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.json" },
    monochrome = true
)
```

Jenkins has [Cucumber Reports on Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cucumber-reports/) plugin for Cucumber reports
This plugin can 'eat' your json file report and will build a beautiful graphs for each build run.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Maria! Can you please tell me what is the format for the cucumber json? Can we manually create this json file?

Comment: This file is an autogenerated file, when you run your feature files, the info is being written there. Pls check for this article, they explained pretty good this flow, I think it will be helpful:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_reports.htm#:~:text=JSON%2DJava%20script%20object%20notation,be%20transferred%20between%20different%20servers. @physio